# awk match pattern and convert number to different unit

Tags: awk, kubectl

I have a csv file that contains this kind of values:

```
vm47,8,32794384Ki,16257320Ki
vm47,8,30223304245,15223080Ki
vm48,8,32794384Ki,16257312Ki
vm48,8,30223304245,15223072Ki
vm49,8,32794384Ki,16257320Ki
vm49,8,30223304245,15223080Ki
```

The columns 3 and 4 are memoy values expressed either in bytes, or kibibytes. The problem is that the "Ki" string appears randomly through the CSV file, particularly in column3, it's inconsistent.

So to make the file consistent, I need to convert everything in bytes. So basically, any value matching a trailing "Ki" needs to have its numeric value multiplied by 1024, and then replace the corresponding XXXXXKi match.

The reason why I want to do it with awk is because I am already using awk to generate that csv format, but I am happy to do it with sed too.

This is my code so far but obviously it's wrong as it's multiplying any value in columns 3 and 4 by 1024 even though it does not match "Ki". I am not sure at this point how to ask awk "if you see Ki at the end, then multiply by 1024".

```
kubectl describe node --context=$context| sed -E '/Name:|cpu:|ephemeral-storage:|memory:/!d' | sed 's/\s//g' | awk '
BEGIN {FS = ":"; OFS = ","}
{record[$1] = $2}
$1 == "memory" {print record["Name"], record["cpu"], record["ephemeral-storage"], record["memory"]}
' | awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3,$3*1024,$4,$4*1024}' >> describe_nodes.csv
```

Edit: I made a mistake, you need to multiply by 128 to convert KiB in bytes, not 1024.

Comment: Regarding `I am happy to do it with sed too` - sed is a stream editor for doing things like s/old/new/, it doesn't have any math functionality.

Comment: @JamesBrown - thanks, I wasn't aware of that. A long time ago I tried to accept an answer and the system refused for some reason, and I didn't try again since. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "if you see `Ki` at the end, then multiply by `1024`

You may use:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3 ~ /Ki$/ {$3 *= 1024} $4 ~ /Ki$/ {$4 *= 1024} 1' file

vm47,8,33581449216,16647495680
vm47,8,30223304245,15588433920
vm48,8,33581449216,16647487488
vm48,8,30223304245,15588425728
vm49,8,33581449216,16647495680
vm49,8,30223304245,15588433920
```

Or a bit shorter:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {
for (i=3; i<=4; ++i) $i ~ /Ki$/ && $i *= 1024} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, traverse through fields from 3rd field onwards and look for if a value has `Ki`(ignore cased manner) then multiply it with 128, print all edited/non-edited lines at last.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/[Kk][Ii]$/){$i *= 128}}} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `numfmt`:

```
$ numfmt -d, --field 3,4 --from=auto --to=none <<EOF
vm47,8,32794384Ki,16257320Ki
vm47,8,30223304245,15223080Ki
EOF
vm47,8,33581449216,16647495680
vm47,8,30223304245,15588433920
```

Comment: that sounds interesting, would you mind explaining that command please? thanks :)

Comment: Which part is unclear to you? See [man numfmt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) for explanation of numfmt.